# How to set an xml image resizing to its parent's height

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I am doing an application that needs to use images, but the ImageView on the HorizontalScrollView isn't resized to its parent's height. How to do? I tried all, like centerCrop, ScaleType, etc... but nothing worked

```xml
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/scrollShareImgHeight">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sharedLinearLayoutImgs"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/loremipsum"/>


            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep Linearlayout's height as "match_parent".

Comment: AH yes I will try sorry, not see not taken like we say in french

Comment: It was exactly that! Thanks a lot